# Bash: Variable substitution in variable name with default value

Tags: bash

i have the following variables:

```
# config file
MYVAR_DEFAULT=123
MYVAR_FOO=456
#MYVAR_BAR unset

# program
USER_INPUT=FOO

TARGET_VAR=<need to be set>
```

If the USER_INPUT is "foo", I want `TARGET_VAR` to be the value of `MYVAR_FOO` (`TARGET_VAR`=456). If `USER_INPUT` is "bar" I want `TARGET_VAR` to be set to `MYVAR_DEFAULT` (123), because `MYVAR_BAR` is unset.

I prefer it to be sh-compatible and as a substitution string. But it might also be bash compatible and/or in a function.

I got these snippets:

```
# Default values for variable (sh-compatible)
echo ${MYVAR_FOO-$MYVAR_DEFAULT}

# Uppercase (bash compatible)
echo ${USER_INPUT^^}
```

I would need something like this:

```
TARGET_VAR="${MYVAR_${USER_INPUT^^}-$MYVAR_DEFAULT}"
# or
somecommand -foo "${MYVAR_${USER_INPUT^^}-$MYVAR_DEFAULT}"
```

This is to switch a bunch of variables between multiple "profiles". In the example, `FOO` and `BAR` are profiles. New profiles should be added easily, in this example there would be an implicit profile named `BAZ`, too, all variables to their default values.

Unfortunately it is not that easy. Do you have an idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
krissi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
TARGET_VAR="$(eval "echo \${MYVAR_${USER_INPUT^^}-$MYVAR_DEFAULT}")"
somecommand -foo "$(eval "echo \${MYVAR_${USER_INPUT^^}-$MYVAR_DEFAULT}")"
```

It is bash compatible. Without `${USER_INPUT^^}` it works in sh too. Its not too beautiful, but working ;)

`USER_INPUT` is only set by trustworthy users, so it will be fine

Answer (score 1):

A `case` statement can handle even more variants.

```
#!/bin/bash

MYVAR_DEFAULT=123
MYVAR_FOO=456

echo "Input: "
read USER_INPUT

case $USER_INPUT in

foo)
  TARGET_VAR=$MYVAR_FOO
  ;;
bar)
  TARGET_VAR=$MYVAR_DEFAULT
  ;;
*)
  TARGET_VAR=DEFAULT
  ;;
esac

echo $TARGET_VAR
```

You can adapt this to your needs - wrap it in a function or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately it does not fit my needs. Sorry for inconvenience. I restated my needs in the question: This is to switch a bunch of variables between multiple "profiles". In the example, `FOO` and `BAR` are profiles. New profiles should be added easily without changing the scripts, in this example there would be an implicit profile named `BAZ`, too, all variables to their default values.